# How to compare an event and its corresponding procedure avoiding E2035 and E2036?

Tags: delphi, events, compiler-errors, delphi-2007

I'm trying to check if an event (`TNotifyEvent`) has been already assigned with a particular `procedure(Sender: TObject) of object`.

Here is my example code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(Button1.OnClick = Button1Click) then
  begin
    //...
  end;
end;
```

In this case, I get the following error message:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(28): E2035 Not enough actual parameters

So, I've tried as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(@Button1.OnClick = @Button1Click) then
  begin
    //...
  end;
end;
```

On compiling, the error is changed to:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(28): E2036 Variable required

How can I check if `Button1.OnClick` points to the `Button1Click`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`... of object` procedures/functions are implemented as *closures*, which contains 2 pointers - a pointer for the implicit `Self` parameter, and a pointer to the procedure/function itself.  You can use the [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) record to access those pointers to compare them directly:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  oc1, oc2: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  oc1 := Button1.OnClick;
  oc2 := Button1Click;
  if (TMethod(oc1).Data = TMethod(oc2).Data) and
     (TMethod(oc1).Code = TMethod(oc2).Code) then
  begin
    //...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Since TMethod is a record can you not just use  " if TMethod( oc1 ) = TMethod(oc2) then "?

Comment: Comparing `TMethod` records with the `=` equality operator has been supported since XE3, when overloaded operators where added to `TMethod`.